# Publish from shotwell to piwigo

Tags: 12.10, shotwell

I'm using Kubuntu 12.10 and I want to publish from shotwell to piwigo. The plugin is activated in the settings but in the online-accounts I can't select piwigo. How can I configure and select piwigo to publish?

Answer (score 1):

The way it's supposed to work is as follows:

1. In the Edit menu, select Preferences, click the Plugins tab, and select Piwigo.  Hit close.
2. Select the photo(s) you want to publish.
3. Click Publish.  Select Piwigo in the combo box at the top of the dialog, type in the details (URL, username, password) and click Login.

From there the publishing dialog should offer options to upload the photos.

(Note that this is entirely handled within Shotwell; Ubuntu Online Accounts does not support Piwigo.)

Does this help?  Or do any of these steps not work as expected?

Comment: The third step doesn't work for me. After pushing publish I'm directly in the Ubuntu Online Accounts. There is no options within Shotwell.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend filing a ticket on Launchpad.

In the meantime you can install an official Shotwell build (i.e. without Canonical's UOA patch).  Instructions are here: http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/install-shotwell/